# Materialize CSS Sidenav Standalone

Tags: javascript, css, materialize, mybb

Recently I have been working on a website (14aag.com) for a community and I have come across a hurdle.

Currently the website has both a collection of static HTML and a forum board (myBB). I have been working on making the theme the same throughout however I am stumped on the menu. As it stands, there is no issue adding materialize.js to myBB but adding the CSS will cause a plethora of issues. As a result of this, I am unable to have the materialize slide out navigation I use on the rest of the site.

I wanted to know if there is anyway to have the slide out navigation code on its own so that I can keep my navigation and not break the myBB forums at the same time?

Thanks for reading,
Flinty

Comment: Well, what are the plethora of issues you're talking about?

Comment: BB Code bars are formatted incorrectly, modal boxes break, container sizes get a swift departure, fieldsets end up blasted off to mars, and so, so much more

Comment: It's most likely because you have conflicting class names (same names being used across different libraries). You will have to decide which one to change manually.

Comment: I don't know if you've had any experience with MyBB, but due to the complex nature of the class and template setup, it isn't really practical to go through and change the classes for everything :(

Comment: Then I would recommend him making changes to the materialize library. It's fairly new and not that complex.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Much and all as I don't want to I guess it needs done... *Sighs*

Comment: How many lines are in the materialize css file if I may ask?

Comment: 9086 lines in total

Comment: Oh boy... good luck :( It's probably just easier to identify which ones are wreaking havoc and then edit them manually.. Though you probably know. Still a nightmare.